# OperationFilter For Swagger not working properly - it shows authorize option on every api endpoint

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, .net-6.0, swashbuckle

I am creating an api with .net6.0. I wanted to add Swagger UI for the api document , which I added and it works for the most part. The only problem I am facing is swagger UI is showing padlock on every endpoint there exists.

Below is my code -
Program.cs

```
    builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    options.SupportNonNullableReferenceTypes();
    options.OperationFilter<MyApi.API.Filters.SecurityRequirementsOperationFilter>();
    options.OperationFilter<AppendAuthorizeToSummaryOperationFilter>();
    options.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo() { Title = "MyAPI API", Version = "v1" });
    options.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme()
    {
        In = ParameterLocation.Header,
        Description = "Please enter a valid token",
        Name = "Authorization",
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http,
        BearerFormat = "JWT",
        Scheme = "Bearer"
    });
    options.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement()
    {
        {
            new OpenApiSecurityScheme()
            {
                Reference=new OpenApiReference()
                {
                    Type=ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                    Id="Bearer"
                }
            },
            new string[]{}
        }
    });
    options.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);
});
```

Here as you can see I am using operation filter to mark the authorize options.

SecurityRequirementsOperationFilter.cs (This my operation filter)

```
public class SecurityRequirementsOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
    {
        public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
        {
            // Policy names map to scopes
            var requiredScopes = context.MethodInfo
                .GetCustomAttributes(true)
                .OfType<AuthorizeAttribute>()
                .Select(attr => attr.Policy)
                .Distinct();

            if (requiredScopes.Any())
            {

                operation.Responses.Add("401", new OpenApiResponse { Description = "Unauthorised" });
                operation.Responses.Add("403", new OpenApiResponse { Description = "Forbidden" });

                operation.Security = new List<OpenApiSecurityRequirement>();
                var secReq = new List<OpenApiSecurityRequirement>();

                operation.Security.Add(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
                {
                    {
                        new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                        {
                            Description="Adds token to header",
                            Name="Authorization",
                            Type=SecuritySchemeType.Http,
                            In=ParameterLocation.Header,
                            Scheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                            Reference = new OpenApiReference
                            {
                                Type= ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                                Id=JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme
                            }
                        },new List<string>()
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

After these configuration I am doing normal CRUD operations in my controllers which are protected and require the JWT Bearer and hence I have decorated these end point with `[Athorize]`  attribute,but in addition I also have two endpoints - /login and /register which obviously I want keep them as publicly available so I decorated them with `[AllowAnonymus]` attribute.
Problem here is generated swagger UI shows padlock on every endpoint  like below -

[image]

How can I get rid of these padlocks on my public endpoints ? What configuration I am missing here ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: [Authorize] and [AllowAnonymous] is applied together on method ?

Comment: @CodingMytra  no on different methods- login and register are decorated with [AllowAonymous] and rest  of the endpoints with [Authorize]

Comment: you are adding AddSecurityRequirement at global level also. as you are adding filter then you don't need to configure inside AddSwaggerGen.

Comment: @CodingMytra Yes that helps , when I removed the AddSecurityRequirement from my AddSwaggerGen configs , it works perfectly :) thanks n cheers

Answer (score 0):

Hope you have already figured out the issue since this is about 1y 6m old. Anyways, you don't need to add

```
options.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement()
    {
        {
            new OpenApiSecurityScheme()
            {
                Reference=new OpenApiReference()
                {
                    Type=ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                    Id="Bearer"
                }
            },
            new string[]{}
        }
    });
```

on your **Program.cs** as you are still adding this onto the Authorized endpoints on your **SecurityRequirementsOperationFilter.cs** filter